# How to bypass Access 2016 2GB limit for offline database?

Tags: ms-access

I know that this is a silly question, but I am building an offline and redistributable tool for my company that operates solely on VBA for Access and SQL. Due to the nature of the client data, we need to create an offline tool that operates various databases.

However, there is one database where we need to import a file of app. 10 GB. Is there any way to bypass Access 2016 size limit offline?

Thank you!

Comment: Doesn’t work. You have to work on [your data architecture or your toolchain](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/167731/bypass-ms-access-2gb-file-size-limitation).

Comment: Thank you! Well, it is time for the company to set up an MYSQL server.

Comment: Total size for an Access database (.accdb or .mdb), including all database objects and data. You can work around this size limitation by linking to tables in other Access databases. You can link to tables in multiple database files, each of which can be as large as 2GB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The free edition of SQL express is limited to 10 gigs. 
You could break up the data into say 10 files, but such approaches are really messy.

The size limit of access 2002 is 2 gigs.

If you take a average name in a mailing list, add a few extra
fields...your record size might be about 120 characters on average in size.

So, the number of records you can store is:

2 gig =  2,147,483,648 Bytes
1 Character = 1 Byte
120 Characters = 120 Bytes

2 gig / 120 = 32 million records

So that table you note likely has 100 million records or more.

So I would say perhaps break out the file into groups of 10 million records. However, to be honest, starting out with a 10 gig file for import is really too large for Access. I would adopt some kind of database engine that does not have these limits. As noted a local free edition of SQL server, or MySQL would be able to handle that file size - you could continue to use access for the front end.